# How to vertically center element in table but not all content

Tags: html, css, centering

I developed following HTML code.

```
        <table style="width: 400px; border-collapse:collapse;">
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" class="border-full" style="vertical-align: top; height: 100px;">
              <span>It needs to be top:</span>
              <div style="display: block; vertical-align: center; margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto;">I need this part to be vertically centered inside rest part of cell</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Effect is like

```
-------------
|first line |
|second line|
|           |
|           |
-------------
```

And i need effect like:

```
-------------
|first line |
|           |
|second line|
|           |
-------------
```

It means I want in one  element let say a header and content. I know I can do seperate td, hide border and that's it. Unfortunately it's part of a bigger table with rowspans so I need to find a wayaround...
I don't know element's height (it's determined by the amount of text in other cell in the same row).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some calculations.

```
divHeight=tdHeight-spanHeight
```

and then apply the appropriate css.Also make your div **display:table-cell** You can do calculations using jQuery

```
$("td").each(function(){
       tdHeight=parseInt($(this).css('height'));
       spanHeight=parseInt($(this).find('span').css('height'));
       divHeight=tdHeight-spanHeight;
       $('.tdDiv').css('height',divHeight);
       $('.tdDiv').css('vertical-align','middle');
})
```

HTML:

```
  <table style="width: 400px; border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class="border-full" style="vertical-align: top; height: 100px;">
          <span>It needs to be top:</span>
          <div class="tdDiv" style="display: table-cell;margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto;">I need this part to be vertically centered inside rest part of cell</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ankur1990/jSJp3/